# Can't hook up UITableViewController to a UITableView created in a xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

Yes another UITableView question. I have a `MainPageController` that subclasses `UIViewController` and I have dragged a `UITableView` into my `xib` in interface builder. I have created a separate controller (with no xib) specifically to handle the `UITableView` and other `UITableViews` like it. Let's say it is named `CustomTableViewController`. It subclasses `UITableViewController` and conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`.

Now, in my `MainPageController`, I would like to create an instance of `CustomTableViewController` and have it "control" the instance of UITableView that I have in my MainPageController's xib. How can this be done? I am mostly confused on what the `tableView` property is on my CustomTableViewController and how to get `myTableView` and `myCustomTableViewController` to connect to each other.

I have tried things like `myTableView.dataSource = myCustomTableViewController;` but nothing seems to happen. My dataSource methods are not even being called.

I am following this design because I want to reuse the custom controller for other table views that will I be using on other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this out and found it working. Here is what should be done -

1) In MainPageController, create a IBOutlet property tableView and hook it up with MainPageController xib.

2) In MainPageController, create instance of CustomTableViewController in viewDidLoad and set the datasource as CustomTableViewController instance -

```
self.myCustomTableTableViewController = [[CustomTableViewController alloc] init];
self.tableView.dataSource = self.myCustomTableTableViewController;
```

This should be enough to achieved what you have described.

MainPageController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface MainPageController : UIViewController

     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

   @end
```

MainPageController.m

```
   #import "MainPageController.h"
   #import "CustomTableViewController.h"
   @interface ViewController ()
   @property (strong, nonatomic) CustomTableViewController *customTableViewController;

   @end

   @implementation MainPageController

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       self.customTableViewController = [[CustomTableViewController alloc] init];
       self.tableView.dataSource = self.customTableViewController;
   }
   @end
```

Comment: It worked. I double checked to see if I had connected my outlet in interface builder and of course I had forgot!

Comment: why is the CustomTableViewController connected to an IBOutlet? Is it connected to anything in the xib or is just the UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController's _tableView is inherent. Even if you create a new class with a xib you'll notice that the whole view is a tableview. When you drag a UITableView into a controller in your xib file or on storyboard, you are only creating a custom UITableView, and you're not going to be able to tell it to respond to another controller. The easiest pattern I can think of right now is this:

1. CustomTableViewController should subclass UIViewController. Define all your datasource functions inside it. Don't use a xib.
2. Because it is a UIViewController you can add an IBOutlet for a tableView. When you create the sublass of MainPageController, make it a subclass of CustomTableViewController, and set the tableView outlet.
3. In IB, set the datasource and delegate of the UITableView inside your ViewController to the class. It should conform since it is a subclass of CustomTableViewController.

Comment: My main page controller is already subclassing another object. Sure this will work, but my goal is to not tightly couple the mainpagecontroller and the tableview. I want to make it reusable.

Comment: in that case, you can instantiate a customTableViewController and add its tableView to the subview programatically. You can't add a subview in a controller in IB that belongs to a different controller. You can instantiate subviews that come from other UIViews (for example, a subclass of UITableView), but they won't have the tableViewDelegate functions that belong inside your CustomTableViewController.